# Catching every exception in Monomac

Tags: exception, monomac

Does anybody know how to catch all exceptions in monomac?

On windows .net I wrap the run loop in a try{}catch and also use:

Application.ThreadException + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

It would nice to be able to get crash reports from my new mac software I'm beta testing.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it is done.  What is the question?

Comment: How do I do this in monomac? None of these methods catch unhandled exceptions. I'm using NSApplication, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException does nothing and wrapping the run loop never catches anything.

Comment: @GordonTruslove The approach described works for me. Post your code.

Comment: I've gone through and wrapped drawrect in a try{}catch{} block, also and new threads and new timers and I think I'm catching all errors now. My app just would quit if there was an exception.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleUnhandledException;` works for me.